# Delay before submitting form not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-submit, google-geocoding-api

I try to add a delay before submiting my form or wait for ajax request before submitting the form. The goal is to get the geo-data (lat+lng) from google api, write it into a hidden (display:none) input-field and then submit the form.

I try it this way. The delay works but after the 5000 ms the page just reloads and ist not submitting.

```
$('#orderform').submit(function (event) {
    var form = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 5000); // in milliseconds

     var address = $('#ustreet').val() + " " + $('#ustreetnr').val() + ", " + $('#uplz').val();

     $.ajax({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=123456789',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
            geo = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ", " + json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            $('#oxmailcheck').val(geo);

            }

    });

});
```

My form is from oxid and looks like this:

```
<form action="[{ $oViewConf->getSslSelfLink()|oxaddparams:"cl=user" }]" name="order" method="post" id="orderform">
<div>
[{ $oViewConf->getHiddenSid() }]
[{ $oViewConf->getNavFormParams() }]
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="[{$oView->getLoginOption()}]">
<input type="hidden" name="cl" value="user">
<input type="hidden" name="CustomError" value='user'>
<input type="hidden" name="blhideshipaddress" value="0">
[{if !$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxpassword->value }]
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="createuser">
[{else}]
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="changeuser">
<input type="hidden" name="lgn_cook" value="0">
[{/if}]
</div>

<input id="ustreet" type="text" class="input-m" size="28" maxlength="255" name="invadr[oxuser__oxstreet]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxstreet ) }][{$invadr.oxuser__oxstreet }][{else}][{$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxstreet->value }][{/if}]">
<input id="ustreetnr" type="text" class="input-s" size="5" maxlength="16" name="invadr[oxuser__oxstreetnr]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxstreetnr ) }][{ $invadr.oxuser__oxstreetnr }][{else}][{ $oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxstreetnr->value }][{/if}]">
<input id="uplz" type="text" class="input-s" size="5" maxlength="16" name="invadr[oxuser__oxzip]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxzip ) }][{$invadr.oxuser__oxzip }][{else}][{$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxzip->value }][{/if}]">
<input class="button medium" name="userform" type="submit" value="[{ oxmultilang ident="USER_NEXTSTEP" }]">
</form>
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal with a delay before submitting the form or maybie submitting the form after the json request wassuccessful and I get my data from google api.

A delay solution would be much better in case the google api is down, then i get no data but the form is still submitting. Or is jquery here the wrong lang?

Comment: well the way you have choose is incorrect and you really should use callback instead of setting a fixed amount of delay.

Comment: well, thats why I am here and asking for support

Answer (score 0):

`$('#orderform').submit(callback)` the callback will be called after the javascript `submit` event, i.e. this function would be called **after** the form is submitted

Rather i would recommend this approach

Use onclick of the submit button rather than $(selector).Submit()

when you get the data from geolocation APIs submit the form using

`$('#orderform')[0].submit();`

make sure that you change the button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` otherwise the button will fire the submit event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#SubmitFormButton').click(function (event) {
    var form = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 5000); // in milliseconds

     var address = $('#ustreet').val() + " " + $('#ustreetnr').val() + ", " + $('#uplz').val();

     $.ajax({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=123456789',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
            geo = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat + ", " + json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            $('#oxmailcheck').val(geo);
             $('#orderform')[0].submit();
            }

    });

}); 
});
```

```html
<form action="[{ $oViewConf->getSslSelfLink()|oxaddparams:"cl=user" }]" name="order" method="post" id="orderform">
<div>
[{ $oViewConf->getHiddenSid() }]
[{ $oViewConf->getNavFormParams() }]
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="[{$oView->getLoginOption()}]">
<input type="hidden" name="cl" value="user">
<input type="hidden" name="CustomError" value='user'>
<input type="hidden" name="blhideshipaddress" value="0">
[{if !$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxpassword->value }]
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="createuser">
[{else}]
<input type="hidden" name="fnc" value="changeuser">
<input type="hidden" name="lgn_cook" value="0">
[{/if}]
</div>

<input id="ustreet" type="text" class="input-m" size="28" maxlength="255" name="invadr[oxuser__oxstreet]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxstreet ) }][{$invadr.oxuser__oxstreet }][{else}][{$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxstreet->value }][{/if}]">
<input id="ustreetnr" type="text" class="input-s" size="5" maxlength="16" name="invadr[oxuser__oxstreetnr]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxstreetnr ) }][{ $invadr.oxuser__oxstreetnr }][{else}][{ $oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxstreetnr->value }][{/if}]">
<input id="uplz" type="text" class="input-s" size="5" maxlength="16" name="invadr[oxuser__oxzip]" value="[{if isset( $invadr.oxuser__oxzip ) }][{$invadr.oxuser__oxzip }][{else}][{$oxcmp_user->oxuser__oxzip->value }][{/if}]">
<input id="SubmitFormButton" class="button medium" name="userform" type="button" value="[{ oxmultilang ident="USER_NEXTSTEP" }]">
</form>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you very much Sir! Just for my understanding, can u tell me the difference between `$('#orderform')[0].submit();` and `$('#orderform').submit();`? Is this "[0]" a check if get data from google api?

Comment: `$(selector)[0]` returns the node of the element , the same we get from `document.getElementById("selectorId")` , and here `$(selector)[0].submit()` is not a jquery method, rather its a native method applicatble on form element , so you can also use `document.getElementById("orderform").submit();`

Comment: Wow this is strange ... now its stopped working. If I click the button the page just reloads but the form dont get rly submitted. This makes me crazy.

Comment: After what changes is your page reloading?

Comment: I just checked if an other variable ist empty, but i switched back to your original code and its still not working. It works like 2 times. `$('#orderform')[0].submit();` just reload the page and fill the input-field with the data.

Comment: Even if I just run `$('#orderform')[0].submit();` in the developer-console its just reloads the page.